# Injectivity of successor of natural numbers in Coq

Tags: coq, peano-numbers

I am a little confused whether **the injectivity of the successor function defined on natural numbers in `Coq` is an axiom?** According to [Wikipedia/Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), it is an axiom (7). When I look at [Coq.Init.Peano](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Peano.html) manual page I see the following:

> Definition eq_add_S n m (H: S n = S m): n = m := f_equal pred H.
>
> Hint Immediate eq_add_S: core.

and it looks like an axiom (?) but what confused me was that in the top of that page it said:

> It states various lemmas and theorems about natural numbers, including Peano's axioms of arithmetic (in Coq, these are provable)

This sentence is a bit ambiguous no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you saw is actually a *proof* of the injectivity of the `S` constructor.  More precisely, it says that the successor function is injective because it has an inverse: the predecessor function (`pred`). (In Coq, axioms are generally introduced with the keyword `Axiom`.)

You seem to be confused by what I think are two related senses of the word "axiom."  The broader sense in logic is that of a "starting point of reasoning" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom#Mathematical_logic)).  The narrower sense is that of an assertion that is taken for granted in a deductive system without further proof.  In [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic), Peano's axioms are axioms in both senses of the word, since they primitive.  In Coq, ZFC set theory, and other systems, they can be proved from more elementary facts.